# how to solve exoplay2 delayed currentposition?

Tags: android, exoplayer

When I stop audio and restart using playWhenReady, there is a little bit delay about the position. For example, The position(when I stop the audio) is 1000. But when I restart changing playWhenReady true, the position is 2000. Because of this, My progressbar is not progressed smoothly. Is there any solution about this?

```
                    if (activeHolder!! == holder) {
                        when (player!!.playWhenReady) {
                            true -> {
                                showLog("player!!.duration, playWhenReady true :"+player!!.duration)
                                showLog("player!!.currentPosition, playWhenReady true :"+player!!.currentPosition)

                                player!!.playWhenReady = false
                                handlerChangeProgress.removeCallbacks(updateChangeProgressTask)
                                showAudioStartButton(activeHolder!!)
                                return
                            }
                            false -> {
                                showLog("player!!.duration, playWhenReady false :"+player!!.duration)
                                showLog("player!!.currentPosition, playWhenReady false :"+player!!.currentPosition)

                                player!!.playWhenReady = true
                                handlerChangeProgress.postDelayed(updateChangeProgressTask, delayChangeProgress)
                                showAudioStopButton(activeHolder!!)
                                return
                            }

                        }
                    }


    override fun onChangeProgressBar(progress: Float, currentPosition: Int, totalDuration: Int) {
        if(player!!.playWhenReady) {

            if (activeHolder?.adapterPosition == audioPosition) {
                activeHolder?.let {
                    it.binding.progressBar.max = player!!.duration.toInt()
                    it.binding.progressBar.progress = player!!.currentPosition.toInt()
                    showAudioStopButton(it)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private val updateChangeProgressTask: Runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            if(player != null && changeProgressPlayerListener != null) {
                val totalDuration: Long = player!!.duration
                val currentPosition: Long = player!!.currentPosition
                val progress = currentPosition.toFloat() / totalDuration.toFloat()
                changeProgressPlayerListener!!.onChangeProgressBar(progress, currentPosition.toInt(), totalDuration.toInt())
            }
            handlerChangeProgress.postDelayed(this, delayChangeProgress)
        }
    }
```

*Log*

```
D/TAG: player!!.duration, playWhenReady false :4166
D/TAG: player!!.currentPosition, playWhenReady false :2459
D/TAG: player!!.duration, playWhenReady true :4166
D/TAG: player!!.currentPosition, playWhenReady true :2640
```

Answer (score 0):

when playWhenReady is true,reset the progress to 0.

is it what you want?

Comment: no.. see the log, the stop position is 2459. so when I restart play, the position should be 2459, but it is 2640. 100ms is jumped up.